# How to get Modulo of a String in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, modulus

I'd like to calculate for an alphanumeric DataFrame column the relative modulo.

In pure Python I could do something like [`int(str, base)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-in-any-base-to-a-string) to convert it to a numeric value. Then simply applying the modulo `%`.

For example:

```
>>> int('5c43466dc6d2870001fk8205', 24) % 64
5L
```

Of course I'd like to avoid a UDF in Python, using only Spark functions possibly.

For example my data source can be something like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        '5c43466dc6d2870001fk8205', 
        '5c43466dc6d2870001fk8206', 
        '5c43466dc6d2870001fk8207'
    ], 
    StringType()
)
```

I'd like a new column with values `[5L, 6L, 7L]`

Comment: Can you explain how you get those outputs from those inputs? What's the base? What's the modulo? How would you do this in pure python?

Comment: @pault updated with a Python example

Comment: As demonstrated by @Enzo below, you're going to run into integer overflow since your numbers are so big. You may be forced to use a `udf` here, unless you can think of a math trick to make your numbers smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@EnzoBnl pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57098672/5858851), there is a function [`pyspark.sql.functions.conv`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.conv) which will:

> Convert a number in a string column from one base to another.

But as he pointed out, your numbers are too big for this function to work properly.

However, you can use some math to simplify the calculation to something tractable.

It can be shown<sup>1</sup> that a base-24 digit number mod 64 is equivalent to the last two digits of that number modulus 64. That is, you can get the desired output with the following code:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import conv, lit, substring

df.withColumn(
    "mod", 
    conv(substring("value", -2, 2), 24, 10).cast("long") % lit(64).cast("bigint")
).show(truncate=False)
#+------------------------+---+
#|value                   |mod|
#+------------------------+---+
#|5c43466dc6d2870001fk8205|5  |
#|5c43466dc6d2870001fk8206|6  |
#|5c43466dc6d2870001fk8207|7  |
#+------------------------+---+
```

The casting to `long` is required and I had a source to explain why but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

---

#### Proof of Claim 1: If `d` is a base-24 representation of a number, then `d % 64 = d_low % 64`, where `d_low` represents the two least significant digits of `d`.

Let's call our base-24 number `d`. If `d` has `n` digits, it can be represented in decimal (base-10) as follows:

```python
d = sum( di * 24**i for i in range(n) )
```

Where `di` represents the `ith` digit in `d` in base-10.

We can equivalently write this sum as the sum of the lower 2 digits (2 least significant digits) and the upper `n-2` digits (given `n > 2`):

```python
d = sum( di * 24**i for i in range(2) ) + sum( di * 24**i for i in range(2, n) )
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#           let's call this d_low                  let's call this d_high

d = d_low + d_high
```

Observe that `d_high` can be simplified by factoring out `24**2`

```python
d_high = (24**2) * sum( di * 24**(i-2) for i in range(2, n) )
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                   for simplicity, let's call this x

d_high = (24**2) * x
```

Thus we have:

```python
d = d_low + (24**2) * x
```

Now the number you want to calculate is `d % 64`.

```python
d % 64 = (d_low + (24**2) * x) % 64
```

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323271/how-to-find-modulo-of-a-sum-of-numbers), `(x + y) % z = ( x % z + y % z ) % z`, so the above can be written as:

```python
d % 64 = (d_low % 64 + ((24**2) * x) % 64) % 64
```

Now observe that `24**2` is an even multiple of `64` (because they both contain `2**6`.

```python
24**2=((2**3)*3)**2=((2**6)*(3**2))=64*9`.
```

Thus `(24**2) % 64 = 0`. It follows then that `((24**2) * x) % 64 = 0`.

Consequently we can now write:

```python
d % 64 = (d_low % 64 + 0 % 64) % 64
       = (d_low % 64 + 0) % 64
       = d_low % 64
```

Comment: That's a nice trick ! I'm curious to see general rules for "Given a `m` in base 10 and an `original_base`, what is the minimal number `n` of digits in order to have for all  `a` in `original_base`: `a % m == truncated(a, n) % m`".

Comment: @EnzoBnl you can't really come up with a rule that works for all cases, but in general you have to find the minimum number of digits, `i`, where `original_base**i` is a factor of `m`. There won't always be a number, for instance if `m` is a prime number (and `original_base` is not a factor of `m`).

Comment: @EnzoBnl it will only be possible to reduce the number of digits if the set of prime factors of `original_base` contains all of the prime factors of `m`. Thus you can generalize it by computing the prime factors of both numbers, then figuring out what power to raise `original_base` in order to get the full factorization of `m`.

Answer (score 1):

- There is a built-in function made to do conversions between bases: `conv(num, from_base, to_base)`, `conv('100', 2, 10)` gives `4`. I point you to its [documentation](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#conv).
- Assuming you manipulate a base 24, you can achieve the operation 'modulo `n`' with `substr(conv(value, 24, n), -1)`.
- But I think things won't work because in your case values are superior to `2^64-1`, i.e. in base 24 : `l12ee5fn0ji1if`.